# codeigniter rest api returns strange output

Tags: rest, api, codeigniter

I created a rest api with **Codeigniter** & chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver.

It works fine, but when I try with Postman extension or Axios js it returns something strange.
If I open rest api url in another browser normal tab and then I use postman/axios js, then it works as aspected.

### Error screen:

[image: Codeigniter api error]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your provider is running anti DoS software.

See here:

https://exceptionshub.com/wordpress-rest-api-not-working-with-postman.html

(Which links to this: https://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/102642/ddos-protection-for-website-with-vddos-proxy-protection-vddos-layer4-mapping)

And down in this discussion:

https://github.com/SSilence/selfoss/issues/803

The two answers suggest changing providers or asking them to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks.i tested it in an android app.same things happend.

im newbee so i can't get what is going on..